# Differential Equations Power Series problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, frobenius-method

The given equation is:
$$x^2y''+xy'+\left(x-5\right)y=0$$

Using the method of frobenius where:
$$y = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_nx^{n+r}$$

$$y' = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n(n+r)x^{n+r-1}$$

$$y'' = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n(n+r)(n+r-1)x^{n+r-2}$$
I substituted the y, y', y'' into the original equation:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n(n+r)(n+r-1)x^{n+r} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n(n+r)x^{n+r} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_nx^{n+r+1} - 5\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_nx^{n+r}=0$$

After I re-indexed the the third summation, I simplified it to:

$$A_2 x^{r+1} +\sum_{n=0}^\infty (A_n(n+r)^2-5A_n+A_{n+1})x^{n+r} = 0 $$

Is this correct so far?
If so, what do I need to do to find the series solution?

Thank you